# Remove the [monitor]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I met [monitor](/questions/tagged/monitor) and expected it would be about [screen](/questions/tagged/screen)s, but not so... it's about [monitoring](/questions/tagged/monitoring).

Comment: Questions about a monitor that is a piece of hardware would seem to be off-topic on SO.  That said, perhaps the two tags should be merged.  There seems to be little difference between them.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: From the comments on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271861/external-monitor-flashing-black-and-forth), it doesn't even seem anyone knows it's off-topic.

Comment: @Jamal Indeed.  It is used to mean the piece of hardware for many questions.  IMO [tag:monitor] should be removed.

Comment: Monitor could be a valid flag for a multithreading object. But looking at the questions for that tag, it's not...